# select each row from a table that display data from php while loop

Tags: php, mysql, html

say I have a table with 5 variables like

1 Jhon 
2 Emma
3 Sal
4 Eric
5 Linda

The data is echoed into table using php `MySQL_fetch_array('something')`
what I want is imagine there is edit button in next row when the user clicks desired row I want to redirect somewhere with that row id like

```
www.iol.com/select?id=1
```

and soon 
please help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I image you have a loop outputting all of the data. What you need to do is just output some HTML with a link. Something like this would work:

```
<a href="/select?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">User profile</a>
```